# is there any package can draw waterfalls and support facet_wrap/grid

Tags: r

I know `library(waterfalls)` can draw waterfall , but it isn't support facet_wrap/grid . Is there any package can draw waterfalls and support facet_wrap/grid ? or other each way to reach this goal . Thanks!

Comment: I worked on a waterfall chart last year and didn't use any package besides `ggplot2`.  I was following [this post:](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2010/05/ggplot2-waterfall-charts) for guidance and did a fair amount of dataframe manipulation before I got to drawing the plot (so... not quick).  But **I am guessing** you could ultimately facet_wrap it if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the post in ScottyJ's comment, I tried a example. Just mark it!

```
water_data <- data.frame(item=c('income','cost','exp','profit'),value=c(10,-5,-3,2))

wt_data <- water_data %>% mutate(mx=row_number(),
  mtype=if_else(item %in% c('income','profit'),'nest','per' ),
                      cumvalue=cumsum(value ),
  start=lag(cumvalue,default =0),
  end = lead(start,default =0))


wt_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill=mtype))+
  geom_rect(aes(x=item,xmin=mx-0.3,xmax=mx+0.3,ymax=end,ymin=start))
```